# Event when a window gets maximized/un-maximized

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an event that is fired when you maximize a Form or un-maximize it?

Before you say `Resize` or `SizeChanged`: Those get only fired if the `Size` actually changes. If your window happens to be equal in size to the maximized window, they do not fire. Location looks like the next best bet, but that again feels like gambling on a coincidence.

Comment: You could test location, but that begs the question as to what event would fire your test...

Comment: Would testing the windowstate in the form's activate event help?

Comment: By "un-maximized", you probably mean "restored".

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do this by overriding WndProc:

```
protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
{
    if( m.Msg == 0x0112 ) // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    {
        // Check your window state here
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr( 0xF030 ) ) // Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
        {
              // THe window is being maximized
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

This should handle the event on any window.   `SC_RESTORE` is `0xF120`, and `SC_MINIMIZE` is `0XF020`, if you need those constants, too.

Comment: You may notice that this does not work when maximizing by double-clicking the titlebar. According to MSDN, "In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low-order bits of the wParam parameter are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct result when testing the value of wParam, an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx) Therefore, the comparison should be "(m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFF0) == 0xF030" or something similar.

Comment: int wParam = (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFF0);
if (wParam == 0xF030 || wParam == 0xF020 || wParam == 0xF120) 
{
   DoUpdate();
} worked for me. Also i called base.WndProc(ref m); before to be able to use updated window parameters

Comment: See Lorenzo's answer for a modification that also handles the restore event. (I think it is helpful having explicitly in the code sample).

Comment: 0xF120 is when maximizing from the windows bar

Comment: works correctly, when modified according to Gorkem's suggestion

Answer (score 80):

Suprising that no one mentioned the inbuilt .NET method.

This way you don't need to override the Window Message Processing handler.

It even captures maximize/restore events caused by double-clicking the window titlebar, which the WndProc method does *not*.

Copy this in and link it to the "Resize" event handler on the form.

```
    FormWindowState LastWindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // When window state changes
        if (WindowState != LastWindowState) {
            LastWindowState = WindowState;


            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) {

                // Maximized!
            }
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal) {

                // Restored!
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution looks so much prettier than going down to the WinAPI level. Has much better chances working on Mono.

Comment: This answer does not address the actual question, which was about the fact that the resize event doesn't even fire in certain circumstances.

Comment: Dave Cousineau, this works nicely. Tested in these cases (clicking the window maximize button, double clicking the window title bar, and setting form WindowState programmatically). Is there another way to Maximize/Restore that I did not list?

Comment: You should always record your last "normal" window size, so you can save it's size to your settings should the user exit the program when the window is maximized, that way when the user comes back to a maximized window, you will have written the original window size back, so when they restore the window, it doesn't just restore to the same size as the window when it is maximized. This is one way to prevent that annoying saved-the-window-sizes-but-maximized-window-restored-to-same-size problem, which then makes the program look unprofessional in my opinion that is.

Answer (score 14):

Another little addition in order to check for the restore to the original dimension and position after the maximization:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    if (m.Msg == 0x0112)
    {
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030) // Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
            || m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF120)) // Restore event - SC_RESTORE from Winuser.h
        {
            UpdateYourUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the code is even simpler than that. You don't need to save the lastState because the `WindowState` is checked anytime when the event is fired.

```cs
private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        spContainer.SplitterDistance = 1000;
    }
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        spContainer.SplitterDistance = 500;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and I could solve it without overriding.
Because I have a **PictureBox** in dock mode "Fill" I could use it's **SizeChanged** event, which fired also on maximizing the window.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this part of code will be useful.

```
            if (m.Msg == User32.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING && IsHandleCreated)
            {
                User32.WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = new User32.WINDOWPLACEMENT();
                wp.length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(User32.WINDOWPLACEMENT));
                User32.GetWindowPlacement(Handle, ref wp);

                switch (wp.showCmd)
                {
                    case User32.SW_RESTORE:
                    case User32.SW_NORMAL:
                    case User32.SW_SHOW:
                    case User32.SW_SHOWNA:
                    case User32.SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE:
                        _windState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        if (wp.showCmd == User32.SW_RESTORE)
                            Update();
                        break;

                    case User32.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
                        _windState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                        SetMaximumSize();

                        break;

                    case User32.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
                    case User32.SW_MINIMIZE:
                    case User32.SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE:
                        _windState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                        break;
                }
            }

    private void SetMaximumSize()
    {
        Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);
        if (screen != null && !screen.WorkingArea.IsEmpty)
        {
            int sizeDiff = this.Size.Width - this.ClientSize.Width;
            var maxSize = new Size(screen.WorkingArea.Width + sizeDiff, screen.WorkingArea.Height + sizeDiff);
            this.MaximumSize = maxSize;
        }
    }

    #region Window State

    public const int SW_NORMAL = 1,
        SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2,
        SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3,
        SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4,
        SW_SHOW = 5,
        SW_MINIMIZE = 6,
        SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7,
        SW_SHOWNA = 8,
        SW_RESTORE = 9;

    #endregion Window State
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's no obvious event to listen for, you're probably going to need to hook into the Windows API and catch the appropriate message (Google turns up that you'll want to intercept the WM_SYSCOMMAND message: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-234554.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie here so comments not allowed, but this IS a comment to the clean answer by [GeoTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294758/geotarget):

The first line OUGHT to be slightly changed to nullable, to catch if the form is started Minimized:

```
FormWindowState? LastWindowState = null;
```

And a banal suggestion: Move the assignment of LastWindowState to *after* the "if"s, so the user can easily check not only what you go to, but also what it came from:

```
FormWindowState? LastWindowState = null;
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // When window state changes
    if (WindowState != LastWindowState) {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) {
            // Maximized!
        }
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal) {
            // Restored!
        }
        LastWindowState = WindowState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution with maximize, minimize, restore and correct remove of the lower bits which are used for internal purposes only.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
    const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;

    // Call beofre - don't use when "call after" is used
    // dependig on the needs may be called before, after or even never (see below)
    // base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    {
        /// <see cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand"/>
        /// Quote:
        /// In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low - order bits of the wParam parameter 
        /// are used internally by the system.To obtain the correct result when testing 
        /// the value of wParam, an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the 
        /// wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator.
        int wParam = (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFF0);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Received param: { Convert.ToString(wParam, 16) } ");

        if (wParam == SC_MAXIMIZE)
        {
            
        }

        if (wParam == SC_MINIMIZE)
        {
            
        }

        if (wParam == SC_RESTORE)
        {
            
        }
    }

    // Call after - don't use when "call before" is used
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
' Great tip. So if it helps to VisualBasic In Code
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = &HF030
' # WndProcess 루프함수
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg.Equals(WM_SYSCOMMAND) Then
        If (m.WParam.ToInt32.Equals(SC_MAXIMIZE)) Then
            Me.p_FullScreen()
            Return
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```