# OnResize not firing on anchored controls when the form maximises

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xna

I have a custom control that is anchored on all four sides. I have overridden its OnResize function as I need to update a matrix when the controls aspect ratio changes. This all works fine when you resize the form by grabbing the edges, but when the form is maximised the custom controls OnResize does not get called. The control still resizes as it should so I end up with a squashed projection. Does anyone know how I can get an event to fire when my control is resized due to its parent form being maximised? I would like for all of this code to be in the control so I don't have to jump through the same hoops for every form that uses it.

Comment: There's no explanation for this.  Post a small project that exhibits this behavior to a file sharing service.

Comment: Is there anything here that helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295999/event-when-a-window-gets-maximized-un-maximized

Answer (score 0):

That should work, as it works on a non-custom control. There may be something in your code or control causing this. You could try using the control's sizechanged event the form's resize event.