# How to resize mdichild form when the user press maximize button on the child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I just want to have my mdichild form to resize when pressing the maximize button and that it will not docked on the parent form.

My initial MDIChild size is 100,100 and when I press the maximize button. I will just have to resize the MDIChild size into 500,500. My problem is that when I pressed the maximize button, it will dock into the mdiparent form and fill all the remaining space that the mdiparent form have.

By the way my MDIParent size is 800,800 so the MDIChild won't go beyond the MDIParent.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295999/event-when-a-window-gets-maximized-un-maximized

Comment: i already apply winproc but still it will dock and fill on the mdiparent form

Comment: The purposed of an MDI form is to have it contained within the parent form, which probably means it will not be shown beyond the edge of the menu strip. http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/573899-set-mdi-child-full-screen-mode

Comment: my MDIparent size is 800,800. so it will not go beyond the edge of the menu strip. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDIChild will dock to the MDIParent form when the maximized button of MDIChild is clicked. This is a property of a child even if there are wndproc applied to its code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void childform_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more insight?