# Windows Store App C# - is it possible to play sound even if the app is multitasked?

Tags: c#, windows-8, mediaelement

let's say I have a MediaElement in my app:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" Source="Assets/alarm.mp3" IsLooping="True" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

myMediaElement.Play() will play the sound. However, when the app is minimized (go back to start menu or do something else), the sound will automatically stopped. I need to go back to the app again to continue the sound. Is it possible to play the sound even the focus of computer is not in the app?

Comment: Chek this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295999/event-when-a-window-gets-maximized-un-maximized

Comment: the solution works well on Windows Form application, not Store apps in Windows 8. good information, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find this blog useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx

and perhaps more specifically:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-776T

Comment: the tutorials in the first link seem to be very specific, but written in HTML + JavaScript language.. I'm afraid I'm working with C#

Comment: sorry about I did a quick bing and found this which may assist. http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/metro-background-audio-c-consumer-preview/

But the key concept to research would be "background Audio"