# Stop Displaying MDI Child form Name in Top OF Parent Form in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net

When my child form load under parent form it displays its title in the parent form title. Is there any way to hide the child form title in the parent title without leaving the child title blank?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us maybe some code as to how you are showing the child

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the form is [getting maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296060/719186) and then erase the form's Text property in that state:

```
private string formText = string.Empty;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  if (m.Msg == 0x0112) {
    if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030)) {
      formText = this.Text;
      this.Text = string.Empty;
    } else {
      this.Text = formText;
    }
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In form1 change ISMDIContainer = True

and for load form2 :

```
  Form2 form2 = new Form2();
  form2.MdiParent = this;
  form2.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion . but I have done this in my project.

Comment: So please send any other solution