# How to trigger Control.MouseMove event when maximized/un-maximized form in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, event-handling

In my form I have several controls and each of them have a MouseMove event hander.  How can I trigger those events (Control.MouseMove) when the form is maximized/un-maximized?  The following code demonstrate how I assign the event handler to each control.  Thank you for any help and advise.

```
control.MouseMove += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dragging)
    {
        if (direction != Direction.Vertical)
        container.Left = Math.Max(0, e.X + container.Left - DragStart.X);
        if (direction != Direction.Horizontal)
            container.Top = Math.Max(0, e.Y + container.Top - DragStart.Y);
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events can only be triggered by the implementing class per definition.
But you can target the MouseMove, Maximize and Minimize event to the same non anonymous delegate created at the same scope as your original MouseMove delegate to retain usage of your local variables.

You will need to create Maximized and Minimized events in your form yourself though, because they aren't provided in winforms (see [Event when a window gets maximized/un-maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295999/event-when-a-window-gets-maximized-un-maximized))

```
public event Action<object> Maximized;
public event Action<object> Minimized;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0112) { // WM_SYSCOMMAND
        // Check your window state here
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030) && Maximized != null) Maximized(this);// Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0XF020) && Minimized != null) Minimized(this);// Minimize event - SC_MINIMIZE from Winuser.h
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Your previous code could then be reworked into this:

```
var MMove = new Action<Point>(mousePosition =>
{
    if (Dragging)
    {
        if (direction != Direction.Vertical)
            container.Left = Math.Max(0, mousePosition.X + container.Left - DragStart.X);
        if (direction != Direction.Horizontal)
            container.Top = Math.Max(0, mousePosition.Y + container.Top - DragStart.Y);
    }
});
this.MouseMove += (sender,e) => MMove(e.Location);
this.Maximized += (sender) => MMove(MousePosition);
this.Minimized += (sender) => MMove(MousePosition);
```