# How to intercept unminizing?

Tags: c#, minimize

In C#, I would like to be able to intercept code when a minimized window is brought back and ONLY there, meaning using Resize isn't working for my case.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Is this your own application returning from a minimized state or some other random application that might be running at the same time?

Comment: There might be a slight difference of how to handle given problem depending on GUI. For winforms see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1295999/1997232).

Comment: The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626928/9132087) from the link in @Sinatr comment seems like the best solution. You could initialize `LastWindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;`.

Comment: sorry for delay, things happened and was away from home for a week. Yes my own C# application

Comment: was able to catch it with your link @Sinatr if you want post answer, I'll vote it. Just mention that the hex code needed in this case is F120

Comment: On SO we prefer to close similar questions as duplicates. If you disagree and think your question is different and answer will be useful for future readers, then post the answer yourself please ;)

Comment: I would be fine, but number I got is defnitely F120, but I'll let you decide I'm fine with both